# How to use FasterRCNN Openimages v4?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use this model.
I am trying to use it to print out the objects that appear in a video
any help would be greatly appreciated
I am just starting out so go easy on me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around and a LOT of trial and error I came up with this

```
#!/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/TensorFlow/bin/python3.8
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import time,imageio,sys,pickle

# sys.argv[1] is used for taking the video path from the terminal
video = sys.argv[1]
#passing the video file to ImageIO to be read later in form of frames
video = imageio.get_reader(video)
dictionary = {}
#download and extract the model( faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2 or
# openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2) in the same folder
module_handle = "*Path to the model folder*"
detector = hub.load(module_handle).signatures['default']
#looping over every frame in the video
for index, frames in enumerate(video):
    # converting the images ( video frames ) to tf.float32 which is the only acceptable input format
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(frames, tf.float32)[tf.newaxis]
    # passing the converted image to the model
    detector_output = detector(image)
    class_names = detector_output["detection_class_entities"]
    scores = detector_output["detection_scores"]
    # in case there are multiple objects in the frame
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        if scores[i] > 0.3:
            #converting form bytes to string
            object = class_names[i].numpy().decode("ascii")
            #adding the objects that appear in the frames in a dictionary and their frame numbers
            if object not in dictionary:
                dictionary[object] = [index]
            else:
                dictionary[object].append(index)
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use it to print out the objects that appear in a video

I interpret that your problem is to print out the name of the found objects.

I don't know how you implemented where you got Fast RCNN trained on OpenImages v4. Therefore, I will give you the way with [the model from Tensorflow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1). [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/object_detection.ipynb). [AI Hub](https://aihub.cloud.google.com/u/0/p/products%2F41b42dfa-e600-4a73-a425-7c5c4d511c3c)

Comment: i when through these but get it to print the found objects (in a photo or video) in the terminal it always gives my found 100 objects and a bunch of object that don't appear in the photo and i can't seem to understand how it works

Comment: In [FasterRCNN Openimages v4](https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1), it's said in outputs dictionaries, there is `detection_scores` key. Use that key to filter out all low score objects. You pick the threshold score. It could be 0.9